# How can I build a nix expression in a local tar file?

Tags: nix

How can I correctly extract a local tar file with nix? There is the `fetchTarBall` function but with the following

```
import (builtins.fetchTarball {url = "file:///home/chris/NewProjects/FinderRelease3/findersearch-13-29-07-04-04-2021.tar.gz";}) {}
```

I'm getting an error of:

```
nix build
[0.2 MiB DL]
error: opening file '/nix/store/jcfqqvfxz9bw5xshs44c4svmrgrd9lay-source/default.nix': No such file or directory
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information
```

Yet if I extract the tar manually and `nix build` from there, it works.

Comment: What is in the store path, `/nix/store/jcfqqvfxz9bw5xshs44c4svmrgrd9lay-source`?

Comment: It seems to be all the sources files relating to the original project. If you suspect the original project is the issue, I could try create a minimal reproducible example.